# How to define host of some strange java-process?

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

Good day everybody!

I'm developing java GWT web application. Yesterday it was working fine - task manager was showing netbeans process and ONE java process - definetely it was tomcat. But today I'm observing netbeans process, java process of tomcat and some unknown java process which causes java heap space error. This strange process eats a lot of memory and it's memory consumption grows dramatically in time.

Probably useful information: the only thing I changed in my app is dropping database and creating it again from some backup. I suspect java JDBC driver can't connect to DB because of probable incorrect user privileges - it is not a problem, queries are performing successfully but strange java process is exists.

Question: How to define host of this unknown java-process? What application, netbeans or tomcat or something else creates it?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Have you tried `jps -v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the reason - I select a lot of data from my DB. It seems JDBC driver was loading incoming data  continuously until memory was enough.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix platform, `ps` has several options that show more than just the process name ("java") - e.g. on Linux try `ps ax | grep java` and you'll see the whole command line that was used to start the java process. It's easy to determine from there what process is running and what they're supposed to do.

On Windows you'll have to find an equivalent - if you're lucky the user executing the process will help you as well - e.g. if it's you or SYSTEM (for services), but the full commandline definitely beats it.